# While trying to save anything via Django Admin Getting Forbidden (403) CSRF verification Failed .Request Aborted Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-csrf, csrf-token

**While trying to save anything via Django Admin Getting Forbidden (403) CSRF verification Failed .Request Aborted.**

earlier It was working fine ,when we deployed the code It started throwing this error .

I tried by disabling CSRF for temporary fix.What can be possible solutions to fix this issue  and why this occurs generally.
Having the same settings file ,django admin is working on dev but on production.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJaYQ.png)

My setting.py file :-

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'guardian',
    'corsheaders',
    'djangodeletes',
    'BruteBuster',
    'admin_honeypot',
    'django_bleach',
    #apps for health check - system monitoring
    'health_check',                             # required
    'health_check.db',                          # stock Django health checkers
    'health_check.cache',
    'health_check.storage',
    'health_check.contrib.psutil'             # disk and memory utilization; requires psutil
    # 'qr_code'
    #    'elasticapm.contrib.django',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    #'csp.middleware.CSPMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'BruteBuster.middleware.RequestMiddleware'

    #    'elasticapm.contrib.django.middleware.TracingMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000"
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'design_studio_app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                #                'elasticapm.contrib.django.context_processors.rum_tracing',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Django soft deletable
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'design_studio_app.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = "design_studio_app.routing.application"

# Celery settings

#: Only add pickle to this list if your broker is secured
#: from unwanted access (see userguide/security.html)

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None  # Disabling the results backend
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Dhaka'
CELERY_RESULT_EXPIRES = 24*60*60
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    'HIGH': 'high_priority',
    'MID': 'mid_priority',
    'LOW': 'low_priority'
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 7,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',  # default
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    # 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    #     #'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    #     'design_studio_app.authentication.ExpiringTokenAuthentication'
    # ),
    # 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    #     'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    # )
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}


SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Frontend
FRONTEND_BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True




# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 1000242880
BB_BLOCK_INTERVAL = 30
# payment methods
CASHFREE = 1

SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
   'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False
}

DEFAULT_ORGANISATION_ID = 1

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("0.0.0.0", 6379)],
        },
    },
}



# Content Security Policy Headers from django-csp package

CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'self'",)
CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ("'unsafe-hashes'", "'sha256-RFWPLDbv2BY+rCkDzsE+0fr8ylGr2R2faWMhq4lfEQc='")
CSP_STYLE_SRC = ("'self'", "'unsafe-inline'",)

CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```